# MELPA pointing to non-existent version of multi-term?

Tags: emacs, package, melpa

I am trying to use MELPA to install the emacs package "multi-term". When I do package-install multi-term, I get "http://melpa.org/packages/multi-term-20141203.1658.el: Not found". However, a more recent version http://melpa.org/packages/multi-term-20150220.1320.el is on MELPA. Why is emacs not installing this version?

Comment: Run `package-refresh-contents` and try again.

Comment: It is hanging at "Contacting host: melpa.org:80"

Comment: Can you browse to http://melpa.org/?

Comment: It works now, for some reason it doesn't stop displaying the connecting string in the minibuffer, even though things have been refreshed. Can you add your first comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if a package is updated in MELPA while you have an old list of packages cached locally.

Update your local package list with `M-x package-refresh-contents` and try again. This should sync your local package list with MELPA, and installing your package should work.

Answer (score 0):

I Have exacly the same problem a fews months i use a proxy to solve that problem.

i add that in my .emacs

```js
(setq url-proxy-services
   '(("no_proxy" . "^\\(localhost\\|10.*\\)")
     ("http" . "myproxy.com:8080")
     ("https" . "myproxy.com:8080")))
```